# How to get a Vector3 out of a Matrix

Tags: c++, math, matrix, directx

I'd like to start stating my goal with this question,
I'm currently creating a small-time game engine in C++ and DirectX and I'm currently at the point where I need to raycast at billboard sprites (the kind that always face the camera) and models.

for my old-styled game, raycasting at billboard sprites is a bit more important now so let's leave the model raycasting complete out of this.

I'm currently using the following code to test against my sprite:

```
for(int i = 0; i < spriteObjs.size();i++)
    {
        BOOL hit = FALSE;
        FLOAT distToHit = 100;
        D3DXVECTOR3 v1 = D3DXVECTOR3((-2.5f*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x,(5*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y,0+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);
        D3DXVECTOR3 v2 = D3DXVECTOR3((2.5f*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x,(5*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y,0+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);
        D3DXVECTOR3 v3 = D3DXVECTOR3((-2.5f*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x,(-5*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y,0+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);
        D3DXVECTOR3 v4 = D3DXVECTOR3((2.5f*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x,(-5*spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y,0+spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);
        if(D3DXIntersectTri(&v1,&v2,&v3,&camera.position,&lookDir,NULL,NULL,&distToHit))
        {
            //cout << "hit target: "<<spriteObjs.at(i)->quad.textureName << "  at distance: " << distToHit << endl;
        }
        if(D3DXIntersectTri(&v2,&v3,&v4,&camera.position,&lookDir,NULL,NULL,&distToHit))
        {
            //cout << "hit target: "<<spriteObjs.at(i)->quad.textureName << "  at distance: " << distToHit << endl;
        }
    }
```

This results in giving a true when looking at a sprite and then testing the ray, HOWEVER, this does not account for the rotation given by the viewmatrix at the sprite itself, so this works for the "front view" of the sprite, but when looking sideways at it (it's a plane so it has no width) you'll never be able to hit it.. ofcourse because it's drawn with it's face towards the camera you still see the front of the sprite as normal.

but in code this isn't reflected, it's just a static quad here, So I need to get the rotation from the world matrix (or inverted View Matrix (your choice)) and multiply/math it with the vector3 defining the vertex's position (in this case v1 to v4)

some extra code on how I've defined my vertices in the quad (so you get why the 2.5 and the 5 come from)

```
VertexPosNorTex triangleVerts[] = 
{
    {D3DXVECTOR3(-2.5,5,0),D3DXVECTOR3(1,0,0),D3DXVECTOR2(0,0)},
    {D3DXVECTOR3(2.5,5,0),D3DXVECTOR3(1,0,0),D3DXVECTOR2(1,0)},
    {D3DXVECTOR3(-2.5,-5,0),D3DXVECTOR3(1,0,0),D3DXVECTOR2(0,1.5)},
    {D3DXVECTOR3(2.5,-5,0),D3DXVECTOR3(1,0,0),D3DXVECTOR2(1,1.5)},
};
```

this would result in a quad looking like

```
   5
----------
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |  10
|        |
|        |
|        |
----------
```

which would turn the sprite billboarding anchor point in the middle, where I only use the upper 0.5 UV space for the texture (the lower parting staying transparant so you won't see it (this helps with the problem of having it look like they are flying above the ground when looked upon from a higher angle)

So.. With enough explanation given and my question halfway, here is the

TL;DR

How do I transform my vertex positions with the rotated version (matrix) back to a Vector3 with their positions in rotated form
(so 1 vertex with 0 rotation at (1,0,0) would be like (0.86,0,0.1314) after retrieving it back from the matrix for example.
(example is just a random number, not resulted from any code or math)

Answer (score 0):

Someone on my FB page commented:

Just transform the vertices with D3DXVec3Transform or something alike, you get a Vector4 but you can simply ignore the w component for a transformation matrix.

-I haven't tested it out yet (I will soon) but I'm 100% sure this will work with my code, as I already have 99% of that implemented in the same function but I didn't use it correctly

Comment: so this kinda works, It has a strange off-set at different angles and positions change with more then 100 on the X at different angles while the sprite is only 5 in width,

I can't completely figure out why..

Answer (score 0):

Crude solution, but it works.. it ain't as nice as retrieving rotations from a view matrix (i'd get quaternions which are almost impossible to convert to eulers) but it works..

```
    for(int i = 0; i < spriteObjs.size();i++)
    {
        if(Vector3Distance(&spriteObjs.at(i)->position,&camera.position) < 150)
        {
            BOOL hit = FALSE;
            FLOAT distToHit = 100;

            float x = 1 * std::cos((angleX+90) * 3.141592f / 180);
            float z = 1 * std::sin((angleX+90) * 3.141592f / 180);
            D3DXVECTOR3 v1 = D3DXVECTOR3((-2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x / 2)* x    + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x  ,( 2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)   +spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y       ,(-2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.z / 2)* z + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);//
            D3DXVECTOR3 v2 = D3DXVECTOR3(( 2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x / 2)* x    + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x  ,( 2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)   +spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y       ,( 2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.z / 2)* z + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);
            D3DXVECTOR3 v3 = D3DXVECTOR3((-2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x / 2)* x    + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x  ,( -2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)  +spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y       ,(-2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.z / 2)* z + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);
            D3DXVECTOR3 v4 = D3DXVECTOR3(( 2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.x / 2)* x    + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.x  ,( -2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.y)  +spriteObjs.at(i)->position.y       ,( 2.5f *spriteObjs.at(i)->scaling.z / 2)* z + spriteObjs.at(i)->position.z);

            if(D3DXIntersectTri(&v1,&v2,&v3,&camera.position,&lookDir,NULL,NULL,&distToHit)) 
            {
                cout << "hit target: "<<spriteObjs.at(i)->objName << "  at distance: " << distToHit << endl;
            }
            if(D3DXIntersectTri(&v2,&v3,&v4,&camera.position,&lookDir,NULL,NULL,&distToHit)) 
            {
                cout << "hit target: "<<spriteObjs.at(i)->objName << "  at distance: " << distToHit << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```